# how to show icon inside a button windowsForms

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I want  to add icon inside a button. Here is my code

```
private void Printbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Assign an image to the button.
    Printbutton.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\\Downloads\\print.png");

   // Align the image and text on the button.
   Printbutton.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
   Printbutton.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;

   // Give the button a flat appearance.
   Printbutton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;

   if (SetupThePrinting())
         printDocument1.Print();
}
```

The problem here is that the icon doesn't appear at first , it appears when I click to the button.

What's wrong here ?

Comment: you added the icon in printbutton_click event instead defining it in Form initializecomponents

Comment: @SebastianSchulz How I do it exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you added the icon in printbutton_click event instead defining it in Form initializecomponents

```
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Assign an image to the button.
        Printbutton.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\\Downloads\\print.png");
        // Align the image and text on the button.
        Printbutton.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        Printbutton.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        // Give the button a flat appearance.
        Printbutton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
    }

    private void Printbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SetupThePrinting())
            printDocument1.Print();
    }
```

Comment: @Sebatian Schulz Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Assign an image to the button.
        button1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\Yourfolder");
        // Align the image and text on the button.
        button1.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        button1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        // Give the button a flat appearance.
        button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your print code.
    }
```